# Am I authorized to work in this country?

Tags: applications, united-states, visa, canada, employment

I live and Canada and I'm currently looking for job opportunities in the USA. When a job application says:

*"Are you authorized to work in the country(ies) outlined in this job?"*

**Would I select Yes or No?**

See the problem here is I'm not sure whether the company means, *currently* or *in the future if I'm given an offer to work there.* At the moment I do not possess a work Visa to be employed in America but given the situation of me getting a job with the company I would be able to obtain one.

Comment: You are not at this moment in time. But add a note that you can get a visa

Comment: Unfortunately there is no option to add any notes. The application is online with a simple yes/no check box.

Comment: So it is no. But there will be a bit in to online form to point out that you can get a visa

Comment: There is not. No sections where I can add in any notes of any sort.

Comment: Or they will assume yhatb"no" means you'll need a visa. I'd just check the "no" box and go on.

Comment: Does it not have a part to explain why are you are applying for the job and gives you free text

Comment: @EdHeal Yes actually, I can upload a cover letter and I plan on mentioning it in there. Thank you!

Comment: _given the situation of me getting a job with the company I would be able to obtain one._ **NO**.  **Only USCIS** has the authority to say you would be able to obtain work visa. Having a job offer with the company has no guarantee tthat you'll have the visa.

Comment: @scaaahu, The web site from USCIS makes it pretty clear what he needs as a Canadian. http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/tn-nafta-professionals For all you know, that's what he's basing his information on. In any case, I agree that he should check "no" and explain things further in his cover letter.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk The OP said he lives in Canada (he did not make it clear). He did not say he is Canadian. There is a huge difference between living in Canada and a Canadian citizen as far as USCIS is concerned.

Comment: To the OP, are you a Canadian citizen?

Comment: @scaaahu Yes, I have Canadian citizenship

Comment: @PaulWarnick Then NAFTA should be applicable to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The company wants to know if you will require a work visa or other such accommodation should you be hired.

It is the same as when they ask "Do you have clearance?" (for military or government jobs). They are not asking *"Can you obtain clearance in the future?"* they are asking if you have it now or will they have to wait for you to obtain it.

So, again, it is not asking for your capability to obtain work authorization - it is asking if you are authorized now - the answer to which is *No*.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a visa yet, then you're not authorised, so click 'No'