# What is US work permit?

Tags: job-offer, job-acceptance, law

I was sending my job applications to companies to some companies in US. Almost each of them was asking for US work permit. I'm an Indian.

I was applying for jobs which offers relocation and visa sponsorship.

I took the question as this **Do you have any legal suit filed against you which prevent you from working in US?**

So I answered as *not applicable* and *YES, I have a work permit*

Is there some special permit which I have to take to apply to those kind of companies?

Comment: Welcome to the site xameeramir. I want to point out that we generally encourage you not to accept an answer too quickly. You may want to give other people a chance to submit an answer as well and accepting early tends to discourage other people from replying. You are free to change or remove the mark-as-answered tick at any time and you may want to do so and wait [one or two days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/260382) before evaluating the answers you received and accepting the one that you found the most helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I took the question as this **Do you have any legal suit filed against
>   you which prevent you from working in US?**

This has nothing to do with a lawsuit.

Almost certainly the US companies were asking if you are able to work in the US without being sponsored.

You should have answered No.

See: [Am I authorized to work in this country?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56910/am-i-authorized-to-work-in-this-country)

Comment: It cleared all my doubts! So crazy me.

Comment: When you aren't sure what a question means,  the first step should usually be to ask the questioner to clarify... or to provide an answer that starts with. "I'm not sure, but you seem to be asking..."